# Thunderbird Mail Application showing .xml and .txt files as inline message rather than real attachments

Tags: thunderbird

i am using Thunderbird 31.4.0 in which all incomming mail messages generated from java application has attachment of xml and txt extension files
and the problem is that all xml and txt attachment files are embodied in mail body itself ie all attachments are inlined with mail body.

i have unchecked : View->Display attachments inline

It is ok for .xml extension files but not for .txt files.

All is working perfectly in other Mail application, Like gmail,ymail..etc are showing attachments correctly.

Is anyone has any idea to solve this issue.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could upgrade to version 38.2 or higher.  It doesn't display `txt/xml` inline any more once you unchecked that option.